# Give a role permission to add and edit their terms in a taxonomy

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users

In Drupal 7 I am trying to give users the ability to add terms to a taxonomy and then edit only the terms they have created.

I'm using the [Taxonomy access fix](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access_fix) module to give users permission to add terms in specific taxonomies. However, Drupal does not provide an "edit own terms" permission like it does for nodes. Users can either edit all terms in the taxonomy, or not have editing permission.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If drupal doesn't provide any "edit own terms" permission, then better do it programatically if you wish.

While accessing term page, load/check for the owner of term and allow them to access edit page.

Answer (score -2):

There are a number of modules that do this that can be found through a simple google search.

https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=taxonomy+access+drupal+permissions&oq=taxonomy+access+drupal+permissions

This looks great https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access